# How do I use the wikipedia dump as a Gensim model?

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I am trying to use the English Wikipedia dump (https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2) as my pre-trained word2vec model using `Gensim`.

```
from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors

model_path = 'enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2'
w2v_model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(model_path, binary=True)
```

when I do this, I get

```
   342     with utils.smart_open(fname) as fin:
    343         header = utils.to_unicode(fin.readline(), encoding=encoding)
--> 344         vocab_size, vector_size = (int(x) for x in header.split())  # throws for invalid file format
    345         if limit:
    346             vocab_size = min(vocab_size, limit)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '<mediawiki'
```

Do I have to re-download or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That dump file includes the actual Wikipedia articles in an XML format – no vectors. The `load_word2vec_format()` methods only load sets-of-vectors that were trained earlier.

Your `gensim` installation's `docs/notebooks` directory includes a number of demo Jupyter notebooks you can run. One of those, `doc2vec-wikipedia.ipynb`, shows training document-vectors based on the Wikipedia articles dump. (It could be adapted fairly easily to train only word-vectors instead.)

You can also view this notebook online at:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/doc2vec-wikipedia.ipynb

Note that you'll learn more from these if you run them locally, and enable logging at the INFO level. Also, this particular training may take a full day or more to run, and require a machine with 16GB or more or RAM.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how doc2vec differs from word2vec? Will I still be able to vectorize a single word? Or does it receives the entire document as an input?

Comment: `Doc2Vec` extends `Word2Vec` with a method of learning vectors for longer texts. Some modes of `Doc2Vec` also create word-vectors, but if you only need word-vectors, just use `Word2Vec`. As mentioned, it should be easy to change the notebook example to use `Word2Vec` instead.